# Scene physicsbody not working when using init(size:) for my scene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Instead of using the suggested initializer, `init(fileNamed: String)`, I want to use the designated initializer, `init(size: CGSize)`, in my SKScene class.

When I do this my scene is the correct size but the `physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)` does not work for my scene.

Does the `init(fileNamed)` initializer do anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Define "does not work" ;)

Comment: It allows my nodes with proper physicbodies to move off the scene. It does work if i create a rectangle with the size of the frame and pass it that instead. But that feels like a roundabout way to do that. If i had to guess what the problem was is that the frame is places at (0, 0) which is the center of the screen instead of the top right.